# Any addons for contacts for Plone 4.1

Tags: python, plone

Hi I have tried UpfrontContacts, collective.contacts couldn't get to build the zope.conf. Any for the version of Plone i.e 4.1 ? Please let me know the exact steps to implement the same also. Also tried Membrane. But don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Products.PressRoom is the answer yahooo! :)